# React.Children.count or children.length?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing on migration from class based components to functional components.
My problem is legacy codes counts react comopnents using **children.length** which is different my previous use **React.Children.count(children)**.

Any differences between two of these? which one is better?

```js
  ...
  const SomeParentFC = () => {
  const arrays = [1,2,3,4,5]
  function renderSomething() {
    return arrays.map((value,index) => {
      <SomeReactComponent key={index}>value</SomeReactComponent> 
    })
  }
  return(
    <SomeChildFC> 
       { renderSomething() } 
    </SomeChildFC> 
  )
}

  const SomeChildFC = ({children}) => {
  const getMyChildrenCount = () => {
    ? ??? 
  }

  return (
    <>
    </> 
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can use `React.Children.count` , documentation here: [reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrencount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrencount)

```
const getMyChildrenCount = () => React.Children.count(children);
```